# Keras model.predict() throwing ValueError

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tf.keras, conv-neural-network

X and Y is of shape (89362, 5) and (89362,) repectively.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y,
                                                    test_size = 0.3, 
                                                    random_state = 1)


x_train.shape, y_train.shape = ((62553, 5), (62553,))
x_test.shape, y_test.shape = ((26809, 5), (26809,))
```

Reshaped the vectors to:

```
torch.Size([1, 62553, 5]), torch.Size([1, 62553])
torch.Size([1, 26809, 5]), torch.Size([1, 26809])
```

The model is defined as

```
n_steps = 62553
n_features = 5


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(62553))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, verbose=0)
```

While predicting with x_test, it throws value error

```
yhat = model.predict(x_test, verbose=0)
print(yhat)

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_4_input to have shape (62553, 5) but got array with shape torch.Size([26809, 5])
```

Comment: I don't think that you need this line: model.add(Dense(62553)).

Comment: Is it my idea, or you are using Pytorch tensors with Keras?

Comment: @desertnaut you are right, that was mistake. I was trying out both Pytorch and Keras and that code got mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are specifying a fixed size here:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
```

Once you pass something else to the model, the model is still expecting that fixed size with dimensions:

```
n_steps = 62553
n_features = 5
```

Removing the input_shape parameter should correct this issue:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
```

I hope that this helps you.